# XNA game for Xbox360

Tags: xna-4.0, xbox360

I learn XNA 4 and made a simple game for Windows. Now i want to run it on Xbox360.
I choose "Create Copy of Project for Xbox360" and build it. After that i have in bin folder two files with extensions .exe and .pdb and Content folder.
How i can run this on Xbox360?